# How to check inner part of 3D array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D array `a = np.array([[[1,1],[1,1]],[[1,0],[1,0]]])` and I need to check which members are equal to `[1,1]` and set all other members to `[0,0]` How should I approach this?

Comment: Is my edited version more on topic?

Comment: No it isn't. Please read the links in my comment above and [the question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with the appropriate axis to find the subarrays. Given that you can assign a new value:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1, 1],
            [1, 1]],

           [[1, 0],
            [1, 0]],

           [[1, 1],
            [1, 0]]
])
a[np.where(np.all(a == [1,1], axis=2))] = [0, 0]
```

This will give you an `a` with:

```
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [1, 0]]])
```

Comment: What does the argument "axis" do?

Comment: Axis tells it which level of the multi dimensional array to check. Since you are checking for this subarray deep in structure it is needed. See: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-axis